# why is there a NullPointerException when using loadstrings but not on normal string? (Processing)

Tags: arrays, string, nullpointerexception, processing

newbie here,

probably a logical error so, I started with a set of codes without `class` and then I tried to redo it by using it with the same outcome, but now I keep getting a `NullPointerException` error on `words[i].display();` what am I doing wrong in my codes? below are my before and after codes... thank you in advance for anyone who can help!

also, I tried doing it with a normal string or without loading an external file and it works fine! why do I get it when I start using a `loadstrings` is there any difference?

BEFORE:

```java
 String [] allWords;
 int index = 0 ;
 float x;
 float y; 


void setup () {

size (500,500);
background (255); //background : white

String [] lines = loadStrings ("alice_just_text.txt"); //imports the 
external file
String text = join(lines, " "); //make into one long string
allWords = splitTokens (text, ",.?!:-;:()03 "); //splits it by word

x = 100; //where they start 
y = 150; 

}


void draw() {

background (255);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {  //produces 50 words

  x = x + random (-3,3); //makes the words move or shake
  y = y + random (-3,3); //makes the words move or shake

  int index = int(random(allWords.length));  //random selector of words

  textSize (random(10,80)); //random font sizes
  fill (0); //font color: black
  textAlign (CENTER,CENTER);
  text (allWords[index], x, y, width/2, height/2); 
  println(allWords[index]); 
  index++ ;


 }

}
```

and the AFTER:

```java
String [] allWords;
word [] words;
int index = 0 ;

void setup () {

size (500,500);
background (255); //background : white
textSize (random(10,80)); //random font size

String [] lines = loadStrings ("alice_just_text.txt"); 
String text = join(lines, " "); //make into one long string
allWords = splitTokens (text, ",.?!:-;:()03 "); //splits it by word

}

void draw() {

background (255);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {  //produces 50 words
  words[i].display();

  }

}
class word {
float x;
float y; 

word(float x, float y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;

}

void move() {
 x = 120 + random (-3,3); //variables sets random positions
 y = 130 + random (-3,3); //variables sets random positions
}

void display() {
 int index = int(random(allWords.length));
 fill (0); //font color: black
 textAlign (CENTER,CENTER); //should make it start at the center
 text (allWords[index], x, y, width/2, height/2); //positions

   }


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare your `words` array here:

```
word [] words;
```

At this point, `words` does not have any value. In other words, it has a `null` value.

Then you try to use that variable here:

```
words[i].display();
```

But remember that `words` is `null`, so you can't use it like this! How do you get the `i` index of a non-value? You can't!

You need to actually initialize your `words` array to something.

If you're following [my classes tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) from your last question, please see the **Creating Many Instances** section.

Side note: please try to properly format your code (the Processing editor can do it for you automatically, check the menus) and use standard naming conventions (variables start with a lower-case letter, classes start with an upper-case letter). Right now your code is very hard to read.

Comment: thank you again for putting up with my questions! T^T at least it's making a little more sense now! I just need to pass this course because I need science courses to get into my faculty... programming isn't really my thing but I'm trying hard to understand it! thank you so much again

Comment: I finally made the error disappear btw